# Ubuntu 13.04 driver for Lexmark X2650

Tags: 13.04, drivers, printing, lexmark

How do I install the driver for a Lexmark X2650 all-in-one printer? I'm moving to Ubuntu step by step from Windows 7, but I don't know how to install my Lexmark X2650 in Ubuntu 13.04. I know some information about Ubuntu, but I'm not a expert. Can you give any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Lexmark provides a driver, and the way to install it for the x2650.  You can download the file, and follow the instructions given to install it.  The file can be downloaded [Here](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=downloadFile&actp=CONTENT&productCode=LEXMARK_X2650&id=DR860&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_US&locale=en&oslocale=en_US&osVendor=LINUX_UNIX&osCats=Ubuntu+9.04%2C+%3Cwbr%3EUbuntu+9.10%2C+%3Cwbr%3EUbuntu+10.04%2C+%3Cwbr%3EUbuntu+10.10%2C+%3Cwbr%3EDebian+6.0%2C+%3Cwbr%3EDebian+GNU%2FLinux+4.0%2C+%3Cwbr%3EDebian+GNU%2FLinux+5.0%2C+%3Cwbr%3EUbuntu+8.04+LTS)

There's no supported driver for 64-bit Ubuntu versions, and Ubuntu 13.04 is not listed, but I would go ahead and try the driver anyway.

Comment: did not work, i get a error message every time i hit download :(

Comment: I see that.  Try this [Link](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=downloadFile&actp=CONTENT&productCode=LEXMARK_X2650&id=DR860&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_US&locale=en&oslocale=en_US&osVendor=LINUX_UNIX&osCats=Ubuntu+9.04%2C+%3Cwbr%3EUbuntu+9.10%2C+%3Cwbr%3EUbuntu+10.04%2C+%3Cwbr%3EUbuntu+10.10%2C+%3Cwbr%3EDebian+6.0%2C+%3Cwbr%3EDebian+GNU%2FLinux+4.0%2C+%3Cwbr%3EDebian+GNU%2FLinux+5.0%2C+%3Cwbr%3EUbuntu+8.04+LTS).  I'll update the answer with it.

Comment: "The installer has detected the operating system does not meet CUPS minimum version requirements. Please install CUPS version 1.2 or higher and run the installer again." this is the error i got, every time i try to install the diriver

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install cups`

Comment: No result, same pb, i get "cups is already the newest version."
:( 
i start to thing that there is no solutuon :(

Comment: Which version of 13.04 are you running?

Comment: i have ubuntu 13.04 ( 64 bit )

Comment: As stated in my answer"There's no supported driver for 64-bit Ubuntu versions".